# Problems after last update

Tags: 16.04, networking, updates, display-resolution

I updated my laptop 30 minutes ago. Now I have lost my network connection and my screen resolution is 800x600 with no other choices available. I have no idea why this happened and rebooting several times didn't change a thing. It is a dual boot system and on Windows boot, there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Forget it, I reinstalled the OS...